# Why is my page not updating with the addition of an element to my array when using React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-state

I am working on a basic react app where I use a form to submit a person's name then it will show up on the screen. After inputting the name, the array does properly get updated, but nothing changes on the screen. This is what I am using to show the person's name. In this case, I have useState on persons so I thought it should update. I am still quite new to React so any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
{persons.map(person =>
    <div key={person}>{person.name}</div>
}
```

Edit:

```
const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
     { name: 'Arto Hellas' }
]) 
const [newName, setNewName] = useState('')

const addPerson = (event) => {
     event.preventDefault()
     setPersons(persons.concat(newName))
     setNewName('')
}
```

Comment: can you show where you setting person function and state code as well

Comment: I added it to the post.

Comment: May we please know when/how `addPerson` method is invoked? Also, when it is invoked what will be present in `event` and what will be current value in `newName`? The Array [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) takes an array (or more) and concatenates it to an existing one (immutably). At the line: `persons.concat(newName)` it is observed that `persons` is an Array - however, I don't see if `newName` is an array too. May be I'm missing something.

Comment: Your problem is most likely to do with `newName`, you should be pushing an object, not a string: `{name: newName}`. So the problem isn't with concat, but rather to do with what you're adding: so using `.concat({name: newName})` should work fine. Maybe double-check the tutorial you're following to see what they are adding vs what you are adding to your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
     { name: 'Arto Hellas' }
]) 
const [newName, setNewName] = useState('')

const addPerson = (event) => {
     event.preventDefault()
     setPersons([...persons,{name:newName}])
     setNewName('')
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to this and now it works. In the thing I was following they did it the way I originally had it, so they must of had some other stuff going on

Comment: This usually works, but be careful when using the state directly. If this function is called a second time before the first setState has finished, it will use the old state and your state will not mutate as you'd expect. That's where the benefit of using a callback in `setState` is helpful. It will always use the newest available state.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, React doesn't think that you've changed the state when you use these kinds of array functions. It's generally recommended to use a callback in your setState call like:

```
const addPerson = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setPersons((prevPersons) => [...prevPersons, { name: newName }]);
    setNewName('');
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I did not know that

Comment: `.concat()` returns a new array, so react should be able to see that state change. The problem is most likely to do with `newName` being a string and not an object, but we don't know that for sure since OP hasn't shown us what's in that

Comment: It was just a name, I do not generally use array methods like .concat() so I was probably not using it correctly